# Get a title and set a url link with it

Tags: php

Good day

I want to edit a custom link(see link below).

What I would like to do is replace the **permalink** of the wordpress post and replace it with a custom url and the "title" at the end. The title will be grabbed from ["title"]

```
<h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($arr[$i]["permalink"]); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($arr[$i]["title"]); ?></a></h2>
```

So this would be something like:

```
h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($arr[$i]["http://mysite.com/"title""]); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($arr[$i]["title"]); ?></a></h2>
```

How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for try this :

```
<h2 class="featured-title"><a href="http://mysite.com/categories/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$arr[$i]["title"])); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($arr[$i]["title"]); ?></a></h2>
```

Comment: thanks, but right before the title I would like to add the following: http://mysite.com/categories - this will be fixed and the title would change accordingly...

Comment: awesome, that works...one more question...how do I strip spaces from titles with spaces in them? eg. Drill Rigs should change to drillrigs...

Comment: Use this : `<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$arr[$i]["title"])); ?>`, See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so muc...I tried the following, but it did not work...why not? <?php $title = "title"; $title = str_replace(' ', '', $title); ?>